# Cache google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth

I'm working on a Python server-side app that uses Google API and Service Account with Domain Wide Delegation auth.

I know how to deal with the auth, the delegation (calling the `with_subject()` method), and the API requests, but what I want is to store the delegated credentials in cache (Redis, p.e.) and then load and refresh it if needed.

With the `google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials` class, we have a `to_json()` method to serialize the Credentials object and the `Credentials.from_authorized_user_info()` method to recreate it later. (https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html#google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials)

This is great and it works, but that's not the case with Service Account Credentials.

The class `google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials` has no serializer methods or constructor helpers to create an object from the dict. (https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#module-google.oauth2.service_account)

Is there another option than "pickling" the Credentials object and storing it in Redis?